# Convert NSDate to time string

Tags: ios, nsdate, swift3, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to convert an NSDate to a "HH:mm" time string. In the past, I could use an NSDateFormatter's stringFromDate method, but now, it seems that method will only accept a Date (NOT NSDate) object. How can I do this? I will accept an answer that allows me to cast an NSDate as a Date, or that allows me to directly convert an NSDate to a formatted time string.

My casting attempts ("_time" contains an NSDate, and _date contains a Date. These don't compile):

```
let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
dateformatter.dateFormat = "HH:MM"
return dateformatter.string(from: (Date)_time)
```

And:

```
let myNSDate = NSDate(_date)
```

Comment: Many object classes have been renamed in Swift 3, losing their prefixes. NSDate is now Date.

Comment: Can you show your try for that ? So I can understand what you just want

Comment: So, why can't I Date(from time: myNSDate), or (Date)myNSDate ? I'm pretty sure that Date and NSDate are two distinct classes, still, and casting seems to be a problem.

Comment: @Jecky:Hang on a few minutes, for me to find one of my attempts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I will accept an answer that allows me to cast an NSDate as a Date

Say `as Date`.

Comment: Hahahaha. I feel silly. Any idea why the (MyType)MyObject usual casting syntax doesn't work, and this does?

Comment: @dylanthelion, Because it isn't `C`, in `Swift` type casting was *always* made with `as`.